# ISSUES with SIGCONT and waitpid() in LINUX

Tags: linux, shell, handler

I'll try to keep it simple. I'm currently replicating a shell for LINUX. I use a linked list structure "job_list" to store all background processes. If a background process is terminated, then it is removed from the list. If a background process is suspended, its status within the list is changed from BACKGROUND to STOPPED. If the process is reawakened (through a SIGCONT signal), then the idea is that the process state inside the list should be changed back to BACKGROUND.

My problem is the following: when I send a SIGSTOP signal to a process, section //1 is executed and its change of state is successfully registered in the list. However, when I reawaken that same process using a SIGCONT signal, WIFCONTINUED(status) will return false, but WIFEXITED(status) will always return true. Consequently, section //3 is executed and the process is removed from the list.

What could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
void sigchld_handler (){

block_SIGCHLD();


job *item;
int l_size = list_size(job_list);
int i, new_pid, pid_wait, status, info;
enum status status_res;

for (i = 1; i <= l_size; i++){



    item =  get_item_bypos(job_list, i);
    new_pid = item->pgid;
    pid_wait = waitpid(new_pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WNOHANG);



    if (WIFSTOPPED(status)){
        //1
        printf("****SUSPENDED\n");
        item->state = STOPPED;  

    }else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)){
        //2
        printf("****CONTINUED\n");
        item->state = BACKGROUND;

    }else if (WIFEXITED(status)){
        //3
        printf("****EXITED\n");
        l_size--;
        i--;
        delete_job(job_list, item); 

    }
}

print_job_list(job_list);
unblock_SIGCHLD();
```

}

Comment: Are you missing `WCONTINUED` in the `waitpid` call?

Comment: Such a simple solution... That was exactly the problem. I wrote "waitpid(new_pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WNOHANG | WCONTINUED);" and it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing the `WCONTINUED` value in your call to `waitpid`.

From the `waitpid` [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

> ```
> pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *stat_loc, int options);
> ```
>
> The options argument is constructed from the bitwise-inclusive OR of zero or more of the following flags, defined in the  header:
>
> WCONTINUED
>
> The waitpid() function shall report the status of any continued child process specified by pid whose status has not been reported since it continued from a job control stop.